# Android onPreviewFrame process raw data

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, bitmap, yuv

I am using Android Studio and I am creating an app that starts a camera preview and processes the image that is returned in the `onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)` callback method of `android.hardware.Camera`. The data that is returned is in `NV21` format (*the default for Camera class*). In this method I receive a `raw` image that I need to convert to an `RGB` one in order to process it, since my application needs to process the colors from the image. I am using the following method to convert the `byte[]` array into a bitmap and then use the bitmap appropriately.

```
        private Bitmap getBitmap(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            // Convert to JPG
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            previewSize = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();

            yuvimage = new YuvImage(data, ImageFormat.NV21, previewSize.width, previewSize.height, null);
            yuvimage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, previewSize.width, previewSize.height), 80, baos);
            jdata = baos.toByteArray();

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jdata, 0, jdata.length);

            // rotate image
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), mtx, true);

            return bitmap;
        }
```

This method works well and I get desired results. But since my preview size is set to the maximum supported by the device that the application is running on(currently on my phone `1920x1088`) this method takes too long and as a result I can only process 1 to 2 images per second. If I remove the conversion method I can see that the `onPreviewFrame` method is called 10 to 12 times per second, meaning I can receive that much per second but I can only process 1 or 2 because of the conversion.

Is there a faster way that I can use in order to receive a `RGB` matrix from the `byte[]` array that is passed?

Answer (score 0):

Actually in my case it was sufficient to remove the **rotation** of the bitmap, because decoding the bitmap took `250-350ms` and rotating the bitmap took `~500ms`. So I removed the rotation and changed the orientation of the scanning. Fortunetly this isn't hard at all. If I have a function that checks a given pixel for the color and it looked like this:

```
boolean foo(int X, int Y) {
    // statements
    // ...
}
```

Now it looks like this:

```
boolean foo(int X, int Y) {
    int oldX = X;
    int oldY = Y;

    Y = bitmap.getHeight() - oldX;
    X = oldY;

    // statements
    // ...
}
```

Hope this helps. :)